# Css code not working

Tags: html, css

Im trying to add a line between each row in a table but its not working. Lines are not being displayed.

Here is my html -

```
<tr class="myline">
```

Here is my css -

```
.myline TR {border-bottom:1px solid gray}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

your css references a `TR` child of `.myline`, do this:

```
tr.myline{border-bottom:1px solid gray;}
```

or even better, applying the class to the `table` not the `tr`s

```
table.myline tr{border-bottom:1px solid gray;}
```

Comment: I'm trying both methods above but they dont seem to work. Do I reference the class within the tr tag the same way ? - <tr class="myline">

Comment: With the first one you do reference the class exactly the same. However, with the second one you would do this: `<table class="myline"><tr><td></td></tr></table>` (adding the class to the table instead of the TRs)

Comment: This doesnt seem to be working, no lines are being drawn - here is my code . thanks - <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<style>
.myline {width:100%}
.myline tr {border-bottom:1px solid gray}

</style>
</head>


<body>
<div class="myline">
<table class="myline">
    <tr><td>sdsdw</td></tr>
    <tr><td>sdsdw</td></tr>
     <tr><td>sdsdw</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: This works, im not sure why. <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<style>
table.myline {width:100%}
table.myline td {border-bottom:1px solid gray}

</style>
</head>


<body>
<table class="myline">
    <tr><td>sds33d1w</td></tr>
    <tr><td>sdsdw</td></tr>
     <tr><td>sdsdw</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>

Comment: on the wrapper div, don't use the class `myline`. So `<div><table class="myline"><tr><td>hey</td></tr></div>`

Comment: OR add the `table.` before the class on the CSS stylesheet.

Comment: AND in the style declaration `<style>` requires a type: `<style type="text/css">`

Answer (score 1):

If no other styles affect the table your code should work. http://jsfiddle.net/MS4Qm/

Comment: Assuming what the OP posted is right, he's applying the style to the `tr` nodes, not the `table` one as you are on the fiddle.

Comment: But he, I think, didn't set the equivalent to `myline2` class. In other words, remove the `.myline2` and set the second table's classes to `myline`

Comment: I missread it... this code should NOT work as you mentioned above (your css references a TR child of .myline, do this:). Exclude he has nested tables. Sorry for that.